# Is it possible to prevent lock screen in Windows 10 uwp?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an app for Windows 10 where there is a slides show, and i want to prevent the auto lock for the screen (turn off).. is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm a new developer will consider that in the future.. thanks, Nasser's answer is working perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this class to do that `Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest`:

```
private Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest _displayRequest;

public void ActivateDisplay()
{
    //create the request instance if needed
    if (_displayRequest == null)
        _displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();

    //make request to put in active state
    _displayRequest.RequestActive();
}

public void ReleaseDisplay()
{
    //must be same instance, so quit if it doesn't exist
    if (_displayRequest == null)
        return;

    //undo the request
    _displayRequest.RequestRelease();
}
```

You can read more about it here:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/how-to-prevent-screen-locks-in-your-uwp-apps

*Please make sure again to provide what you've tried.. have you searched about it?.. Asking directly isn't a good practice as developer :).*

Comment: It works. I'm a new developer but thanks for the tip!